# How to parse a string calculation in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, eval

I am trying to parse a string calculation which is a column within a dataframe, if the calculation is static I can use the eval function. However this doesnt appear to work when you give it a column name.

```
import pandas as pd

calcs = {'a': [1,1],
         'b': [1,1],
         'c': [1,1],
         'calc': ['result=a*b','result=a+b']}

df = pd.DataFrame(calcs, columns = ['a', 'b','c','calc'])
 
print(df)
 
a b c calc
1 1 1 a*b
1 1 1 a+b
```

can you please tell me how it would be possible to evaluate the calculation in the 'calc' column for each row in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), [`df.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html#pandas.DataFrame.eval):

```
>>> df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x:x.to_frame().T.eval(x[-1]).item(), axis=1)
>>> df
   a  b  c calc  result
0  1  1  1  a*b       1
1  1  1  1  a+b       2
```

Or use [`np.diag`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df['result'] = np.diag(df.eval(df['calc']))
>>> df
   a  b  c calc  result
0  1  1  1  a*b       1
1  1  1  1  a+b       2
```

Comment: Very elegant solution!